# Change ngview not use href

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used ng-view to change view. I alwlays set href="/..." in  tag then click on it to change. But now I want to change view in ng-view tag when having an event. How to do that

Comment: can you share what you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

See this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ApSZ4tXtJQZbb3IwwYZ6?p=preview). You can do that by using `$location.path('path-to-url');` inside the method that you call when your event is fired (eg. here shows button click, and checkbox).